# The Jnlp application is not fully signed

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, jnlp, openwebstart

### After running the jnlp file, I get the following error:

**Error text:**

> 

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws from the command line.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:587)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.access$200(Launcher.java:70)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:654)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: The JNLP application is not fully signed by a single cert. The JNLP application has its components individually signed, however there must be a common signer to all entries.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.classloader.SecurityDelegateImpl.getClassLoaderSecurity(SecurityDelegateImpl.java:98)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.classloader.JNLPClassLoader.setSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:387)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.classloader.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:773)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.classloader.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:350)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.classloader.JNLPClassLoader.createInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:423)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.classloader.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:495)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.classloader.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:468)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:579)
    ... 3 more
```

**Error screen**

[Could not initialize application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRDYO.png)

**The Java Console contains the following:**

> 

```
Closing DownloadServiceListener
Waiting for exception dialog to be closed
Launch exception
netx: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. (Fatal: Application Error: The JNLP application is not fully signed by a single cert. The JNLP application has its components individually signed, however there must be a common signer to all entries.)
App already has trusted publisher: false
Operating Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.cacerts
Loading Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.cacerts
Keystore file C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.cacerts exists.
Operating Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.jssecacerts
Loading Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.jssecacerts
Keystore file C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.jssecacerts exists.
Operating Keystore C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJRE-8-Full\lib\security\cacerts
Loading Keystore C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJRE-8-Full\lib\security\cacerts
Keystore file C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJRE-8-Full\lib\security\cacerts exists.
Operating Keystore Unknown
Loading Keystore Unknown
Keystore file C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJRE-8-Full\lib\security\jssecacerts does not exists.
1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=__________,CN=_____,OU=____,O=___,L=____,DC=___,C=RU found in cacerts (C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.certs)
Operating Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.certs
Loading Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.certs
Keystore file C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.certs exists.
Operating Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.jssecerts
Loading Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.jssecerts
Keystore file C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.jssecerts exists.
Operating Keystore Unknown
Loading Keystore Unknown
Keystore file C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJRE-8-Full\lib\security\trusted.certs does not exists.
Operating Keystore Unknown
Loading Keystore Unknown
Keystore file C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJRE-8-Full\lib\security\trusted.jssecerts does not exists.
Operating Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.cacerts
Loading Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.cacerts
Keystore file C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.cacerts exists.
Operating Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.jssecacerts
Loading Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.jssecacerts
Keystore file C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.jssecacerts exists.
Operating Keystore C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJRE-8-Full\lib\security\cacerts
Loading Keystore C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJRE-8-Full\lib\security\cacerts
Keystore file C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJRE-8-Full\lib\security\cacerts exists.
Operating Keystore Unknown
Loading Keystore Unknown
Keystore file C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJRE-8-Full\lib\security\jssecacerts does not exists.
Operating Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.certs
Loading Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.certs
Keystore file C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.certs exists.
Operating Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.jssecerts
Loading Keystore C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.jssecerts
Keystore file C:\Users\Username\.config\icedtea-web\security\trusted.jssecerts exists.
Operating Keystore Unknown
Loading Keystore Unknown
Keystore file C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJRE-8-Full\lib\security\trusted.certs does not exists.
Operating Keystore Unknown
Loading Keystore Unknown
Keystore file C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJRE-8-Full\lib\security\trusted.jssecerts does not exists.
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\218\jogl-all-2.1.5-01-natives-windows-amd64.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\217\gluegen-rt-2.1.5-01-natives-windows-amd64.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\216\appname-client.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\215\guava.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\214\javassist.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\213\reflections.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\211\WellDrillServicesAPI.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\212\EasyChartsMod.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\209\jsyntaxpane.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\210\jogl-all-2.1.5-01.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\181\gluegen-rt-2.1.5-01.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\178\miglayout-swing.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\180\miglayout-core.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\175\jcalendar.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\174\slf4j-log4j12.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\167\slf4j-api.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\166\log4j.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\165\alfa-commons-web.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\164\alfa-commons-db.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\162\alfa-commons-audit-support.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\160\alfa-commons-base.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\159\alfa-commons-config.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\157\alfa-commons-swing-datatables.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\156\alfa-commons-swing.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\155\alfa-commons-axp.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
Jar found at C:\Users\Username\.cache\icedtea-web\cache\0\151\alfa-commons-sapsm.jar has been verified as SIGNED_OK
DownloadServiceListener will be disposed
Download done. Shutting down executor
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/jogl-all-2.1.5-01-natives-windows-amd64.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/gluegen-rt-2.1.5-01-natives-windows-amd64.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/geopro-client.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/guava.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/javassist.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/reflections.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/WellDrillServicesAPI.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/EasyChartsMod.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/jsyntaxpane.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/gluegen-rt-2.1.5-01.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/jogl-all-2.1.5-01.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/jcalendar.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/miglayout-core.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/miglayout-swing.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/slf4j-log4j12.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/slf4j-api.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/log4j.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/alfa-commons-web.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/alfa-commons-db.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/alfa-commons-audit-support.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/alfa-commons-base.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/alfa-commons-config.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
Use cached version of resource location=http://localhost:8888/Appname/client/alfa-commons-swing-datatables.jar version=null state=DOWNLOADED
```

**To run jnlp file I use Open Webstart 1.4.0**

**IDE**

> 

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 11.1
    Java: 1.8.0_302; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.302-b08
    Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_302-b08
    System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; ru_RU (nb)
```

**Apache Tomcat Server / 9.0.30**

Tomkat runs through NetBeans.

**What I tried to do and found out:**

First of all, of course, I checked all the certificates that, in theory, are needed to run jnlp, as if there are all that are needed. Tried reinstalling OpenWebStart, Clean and Build on the project and Redeploy. I tried to run jnlp files from any projects taken from colleagues and they ran without problems. I gave my colleagues my jnlp file and when they started, they received the same error as mine. Thus, I concluded that the error appears only when starting jnlp downloaded from my localhost. What am I doing wrong? I understand that OpenWebStart swears at certificates, but they have already been rechecked 100 times not only by me, but also by much more experienced colleagues.

Comment: Are you sure the files are all signed by the same certificate?